# Transform GET vars from PHP into friendly URLs?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running into a very common issue, I need to transform my site.com/page.php?id=1&title=page-title into site.com/page-title-id

I was thinking this could be easily done adding some mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file but I'm feeling it might not be the most SEO-friendly approach there is, what do you think?

Another way would be to make some changes within the PHP code, but I'm relatively new to this language and I don't know about all the libraries and functions that come with PHP and could make my life easier here.

So far, what I'm doing (Which is not working) in my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN ocasion_system
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php\?title=([^&\s]+)&?
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/%1/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php?title=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And my page.php has

```
//all includes up here..
$page = new Page();
$page->__set('title', $_GET["title"]); //this is how i set up my page interface, please don't laugh

if ($_GET["title"] != NULL){    
        $page = get_page($page, $db);       
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($page);//works as intended when i access http://localhost/page.php?title=default prints all the Page object with that title.
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

I guess a solution in PHP would be much better because I don't want to make search engines think I'm cloaking the site or redirecting or anything, just want the URL to be like site.com/page-title-id or similar.

EDIT: Tried a different approach within the .htaccess

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do, but here are a couple of thoughts. (1) It is fine to use htaccess for this; it's actually better than trying to do it all in PHP alone. (2) Your `RewriteRule`s don't have any `title` parameters, but that's what you're looking for in your PHP script.

Comment: @EdCottrell that depends. I usually prefer to redirect all requests to `index.php` and have a well built `Router` object to take care of my routing.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I probably should be more clear. I do the same as you, but you still need to do the redirect somehow, typically htaccess. Regardless, it has nothing to do with cloaking.

Comment: @EdCottrell No.... all requests internally map to index.php, index.php reads the URL as specified by the client, and determines what to do based on that. No redirects.

Comment: @EdCottrell how is it not clear what i want to do? It clearly says (more than once) that i want to turn my site.com/page.php?title=page-title&id=id into site.com/page-title-id, as I dont know the best approach to do this I would like an honest opinion too

Comment: @SecondRikudo Sorry, I mean you have to do rewrites, not 301/302/3xx redirects. I need more coffee.

Comment: Yes, and who cares about those? They are transparent to anyone outside the server.

Comment: @Dolan The unclear part is that you look for `$_GET['title']` in your PHP code, but have only `...page=...` in your `RewriteRule`s. I'm not sure where you expect the `title` parameter to come from.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Yes, that's exactly my point. OP is concerned about it, as I understand the question, but it's a non-issue.

Comment: @EdCottrell sorry, there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to transform my **site.com/page.php?id=1&title=page-title** into
>   **site.com/page-title-id**

You can replace your current htaccess code by this one (assuming it is located in document root folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

  # Turn mod_rewrite on
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/page\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&title=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %2-%1? [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)-([0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$2&title=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This code will redirect old url format (http://example.com/page.php?id=1&title=page-title) to its new format (http://example.com/page-title-1) and will then internally rewrite back new format to old format (without any infinite loop)

Comment: Okay i moved my .htaccess to where my index.php file is and still doesn't work, I will look more into the apache configuration documentation and mark your question as correct as soon as i get it working. thank you.

Comment: Sorry man but when I go to site.com/page/default-2 it keeps giving 404 message :\

Comment: You did not mention a `/page/` subfolder so this code can't be working. Please provide real url (old and new format) you need

Comment: well I dont really need the /page/ subfolder, sorry man, its just site.com/page-title-id still doesn't work

Comment: Did you enabled *mod_rewrite* ? Did you allow htaccess files in your apache configuration ? Also, do you have other rules in your htaccess ?

Comment: And... do you have a file called `page.php` in root folder ? Where your htaccess and index files are

Comment: I don't have other rules in my htaccess, yes I have the page.php, aaaaaand I didn't have mod_rewrite enabled, sorry man, now It's giving me "This page isn't redirecting properly" when trying to access site.com/page-title-id the index.php file and page.php file are in the same folder as the .htaccess file.

Comment: Ok i forgot something in my code, should be working now (you can try edited code)

Comment: It's working! thank you so much, you know the only thing is that i still need to do a lot of that within my htaccess file, like for example to redirect all 404 requests like site.com/bad-page-title or whatever to site.com, could you provide a simple tutorial or help me a lil bit with that? I'm marking the question as solved now.

Comment: You could simply use `ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?id=404` for instance (no redirect but a better approch for search engines)